# Jupyter notebook input cell limit

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Is there a size limit of an input cell in a jupyter notebook?

As a test I could paste a huge amount of text (500k words), there was no limit warning but the notebook became very slow, almost unresponsive.

Comment: Your question sounds like you are attempting something that you could do more efficiently. E.g., if you have a large amount of input data then read it from a file rather than pasting it into a cell directly.

Comment: True, however this is more of a theoretical question about notebook's capabilities/limitations.